# How can I search for an image, or something like it?

Tags: discussion

In [When animal-identification questions are on-topic](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/when-animal-identification-questions-are-on-topic) it was asserted that photo identification is entirely non-searchable.

Is there really no way to search the net for an image?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to search the internet for an image. There are several search engines which enable this:

- https://images.google.com/ unsurprisingly. Get the web address of your image (it must be on the internet rather than your own computer), go to google images search, enter the URL, and search. You can then refine the search further by adding search terms such as gecko.
- http://www.tineye.com/ is another similar search engine, but it makes life easier when the image is on your computer rather than on the net.

There are also plugins for Firefox so you can right-click on an image and search for it. Tineye has one, but the one I use is called "Who stole my pictures?" which was of particular interest when I was looking for unauthorised usage of some of my photographs.

Comment: Searching for an image, whether using one as a source or not, doesn't necessarily identify the subject. Case in point, the images in a recent question are new images and don't return anything. It's a good way to detect image theft though.