# Is it possible to merge meta questions?

Tags: discussion

I noticed we have to meta discussions about species identification.

[Should we discourage pet breed / species identification questions?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-discourage-pet-breed-species-identification-questions)

[Species identification and the Help Center](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/664/species-identification-and-the-help-center)

Can we merge them together like we can on the main site?

Comment: Well, they're related now that you've referred to both in the same post.  If you're so concerned, edit each to have a link to the other at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, meta questions can be merged by a moderator, but I'm not a fan of the idea for a site like this one. Basically, my thinking is that the growth of the community and the changing thoughts around how things work here evolves over time and the purpose of meta is discuss them as they happen. Meaning that I wouldn't want a new discussion to be clouded by a previous discussion (or vice versa), I would rather it be a reference point instead.

In this particular example, they're not quite the same question anyways and I think the answers lose very real context if a merge was to happen. So, I think it's better to let them stay apart.