# Should this question be moved Biology SE and how would I do that?

Tags: support, questions, migration

I've posted a [species identification question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28646/whats-the-exact-species-of-this-african-giant-snail) earlier and [learned just now](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-discourage-pet-breed-species-identification-questions) that these aren't really suited for this site. So I'd like to have it moved to Biology SE but I don't know how to achieve this.

When I click **flag** below my question and go through the menu being offered, I can only select to move it to pets meta, but not to another SE.

So:

- How to get the post moved to another SE?
- Is this even possible now that it's got an answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've already applied some matching tags. I followed the same steps, but I could only choose to have it migrated to pets meta. Glad everything still worked out so quickly, though. Awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flag it for ♦ moderator attention, as explained in the FAQ [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> If the **site isn't in the list** of available migration targets, or the **question got closed without being migrated**, first read the below points and consider if migration is/was really the appropriate action (in many cases, it isn't). If you think so, you can flag the question for moderator attention and request that they migrate it for you. Simply explain in the reason which site you want it to be migrated. (Please specify only *one* site; don't list all possible sites it *could* go to.)

There are some nice flowcharts there which may help in deciding if a question should be migrated or not.

Comment: I see it's already been migrated just now, but I'll still take a look at the FAQ you've linked. Thanks for that.